# Trying to create a new wallet address but nothing happens

Tags: html, typescript, wavesplatform

I am trying to create a wallet address and a seed phrase for my new crypto coin application for android and ios written in nativescript.

I have tried using console.log and alert function to show the user there new seed phrase and wallet address upon creating an account on my app. but when they press the button and the "wallet()" functions execute nothing pops up but i dont receive an error either just a button that isnt functioning properly.

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { alert, prompt } from "tns-core-modules/ui/dialogs";
import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
//import { publicKey, verifySignature, signBytes, address, keyPair, privateKey } from "../@waves/waves-crypto";
import * as wavesCrypto from '../waves-crypto';
import * as CryptoJS from '../crypto-js';

import { User } from "../shared/user.model";
import { UserService } from "../shared/user.service";

@Component({
    selector: "app-login",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./login.component.html",
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent {
    isLoggingIn = true;
    user: User;
    @ViewChild("password") password: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild("confirmPassword") confirmPassword: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild("waves") waves: ElementRef;

    constructor(private page: Page, private userService: UserService, private router: Router) {
        this.page.actionBarHidden = true;
        this.user = new User();
        // this.user.email = "foo2@foo.com";
        // this.user.password = "foo";
        const seed = 'magicseed';
        const pubKey = wavesCrypto.publicKey(seed);
        const bytes = Uint8Array.from([1, 2, 3, 4]);
        const sig = wavesCrypto.signBytes(bytes, seed);
        const isValid = wavesCrypto.verifySignature(pubKey, bytes, sig)
    }

    wallet() {
        let walletAddress = wavesCrypto.address('seed', 'T');
        let keyPair = wavesCrypto.keyPair('seed');
        wavesCrypto.publicKey('seed');
        wavesCrypto.privateKey('seed');
        wavesCrypto.privateKey('seed');
        alert(walletAddress);
        console.log(walletAddress);
        console.log(keyPair);
    }

    toggleForm() {
        this.isLoggingIn = !this.isLoggingIn;
    }

    submit() {
        if (!this.user.email || !this.user.password) {
            this.alert("Please provide both an email address and password.");
            return;
        }

        if (this.isLoggingIn) {
            this.login();
        } else {
            this.register();
        }
    }

    login() {
        this.userService.login(this.user)
            .then(() => {
                this.router.navigate(["/home"]);
            })
            .catch(() => {
                this.alert("Unfortunately we could not find your account.");
            });
    }

    register() {
        if (this.user.password != this.user.confirmPassword) {
            this.alert("Your passwords do not match.");
            return;
        }
        this.userService.register(this.user)
            .then(() => {
                this.alert("Your account was successfully created.");
                this.isLoggingIn = true;
            })
            .catch(() => {
                this.alert("Unfortunately we were unable to create your account.");
            });
    }

    forgotPassword() {
        prompt({
            title: "Forgot Password",
            message: "Enter the email address you used to register for APP NAME to reset your password.",
            inputType: "email",
            defaultText: "",
            okButtonText: "Ok",
            cancelButtonText: "Cancel"
        }).then((data) => {
            if (data.result) {
                this.userService.resetPassword(data.text.trim())
                    .then(() => {
                        this.alert("Your password was successfully reset. Please check your email for instructions on choosing a new password.");
                    }).catch(() => {
                        this.alert("Unfortunately, an error occurred resetting your password.");
                    });
            }
        });
    }

    focusPassword() {
        this.password.nativeElement.focus();
    }
    focusConfirmPassword() {
        if (!this.isLoggingIn) {
            this.confirmPassword.nativeElement.focus();
        }
    }

    alert(message: string) {
        return alert({
            title: "APP NAME",
            okButtonText: "OK",
            message: message
        });
    }
}
```

So i want the button when pressed a popup appears or it can show it on the same page right above the button the users new wallet address and seed phrase on the testnet